# .htaccess Redirect on a url with spaces in it

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a link from anther website that I do not have control of `http://example.com/one two three.exe`

The correct URL is `http://example.com/one_two_three.exe`

Note the underscores instead of spaces.

I searched the internet and found this code snippet for .htaccess

```
# Redirect old file path to new file path
Redirect /one%20two%20three.exe http://example.com/one_two_three.exe
```

I added this snippet to my preexisting root .htaccess at the top of the file.
But it does not seem to work. My browser does not redirect and I get a 404 error page.

I believe that it has something to do with the spaces in the original URL but I don't know how to handle spaces in the URL.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You could try a couple of things (both untested)

```
Redirect "/one two three.exe" http://example.com/one_two_three.exe
```

or use `RewriteRule` instead of `Redirect`:

```
RewriteRule /one\ two\ three.exe http://example.com/one_two_three.exe
```

Comment: Second one worked for me. I needed to redirect to an URL with a space in it "\ " works perfect!